# How do I pause exception propagation until a separate std::thread completes?

Tags: c++, stdthread

My code is split into one part running in the main thread, and another part in a separate thread. The main thread waits on `thread.join()` at the end.

Now, if the main thread throws, my program terminates immediately, even if I try to catch the exception. I traced it to `std::~thread`, which is unhappy if the thread is still running (joinable).

In such a case, I want the exception to wait until the thread quits naturally, and then continue to propagate. How do I do that? Do I need to wrap `std::thread` with some sort of `joining_thread`, whose d'tor would join?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class foo
{
public:
    foo(const char* name) : m_name(name) {}
    ~foo() { std::cout << "~foo - " << m_name << "\n"; }
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

void doInThread()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "doInThread\n";
}

int doit()
{
    foo fooBefore("main before thread");   // d'tor is never called
    auto thread = std::thread(doInThread);
    foo fooAfter("main after thread");

    // Do stuff, which might throw
    throw std::exception("Something happened in main");

    thread.join();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        doit();
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";  // Never happens - program terminates beforehand
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to read up on asynchronous programming. While I don't recall the C++ specifics at the moment, it just doesn't look like it would ever work the way you've written it because you just calling it in a fire and forget manner

Comment: I understand async programming. The purpose of the code is to simulate the interaction between two non-synchronized pieces of code - I didn't feel it was pertinent to the question at hand.

Comment: I guess I was saying might need to use std::async or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is aborted by calling `std::terminate` function.

When exception is thrown, stack unwinding happens, which means all local variables created before calling `throw` are deleted. When dtor of thread is called, and the thread is in joinable state, `std::terminate` is invoked [according to thread reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

Use RAII to create object whose dtor will join your thread.

```
template<class F>
struct Cleaner {
    Cleaner(F in) : f(in) {}
    ~Cleaner() { f(); }

    F f;
};

template<class F>
Cleaner<F> makeCleaner(F f) {
    return Cleaner<F>(f);
}

int doit()
{
    foo fooBefore("main before thread");
    auto thread = std::thread(doInThread);
    auto cleaner = makeCleaner([&thread](){ thread.join(); });

    foo fooAfter("main after thread");

    throw std::runtime_error("Something happened in main");

    // without throw statement, dtor of cleaner instance would be called here
}
```

Now while unwinding stack, destructors are being called as follows: `fooAfter`, `cleaner` (where you wait until thread is completion) and `fooBefore`.